# sed regexp in a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I want to extract a certain part of a string, if it exists. I'm interested in the xml filename, i.e i want whats between an "_" and ".xml".

This is ok, it prints "555"

```
MYSTRING=`echo "/sdd/ee/publ/xmlfile_555.xml" | sed 's/^.*_\([0-9]*\).xml/\1/'`
echo "STRING = $MYSTRING"
```

This is not ok because it returns the whole string. In this case I don't want any result.
It prints "/sdd/ee/publ/xmlfile.xml"

```
MYSTRING=`echo "/sdd/ee/publ/xmlfile.xml" | sed 's/^.*_\([0-9]*\).xml/\1/'`
echo "STRING = $MYSTRING"
```

Any ideas how to get an "empty" result in the second case.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell `sed` to keep its mouth shut if it doesn't find a match. The `-n` option is used for that.

```
MYSTRING=`echo "/sdd/ee/publ/xmlfile_555.xml" | sed -n 's/^.*_\([0-9]*\)\.xml/\1/p'`
```

I only made two changes to what you had: the aforementioned `-n` option to `sed`, and the `p` flag that comes after the `s///` command, which tells `sed` to print the output only if the substitution was successfully done.

**EDIT**: I've also escaped the final `.` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: You probably also want to escape the final `.`

Comment: @Douglas: true, I hadn't noticed that (and that's why you don't copy and paste code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
basename /sdd/ee/publ/xmlfile_555.xml | awk -F_ '{print $2}'
```

The output is `555.xml`

With the other one.

```
basename /sdd/ee/publ/xmlfile.xml | awk -F_ '{print $2}'
```

The output is an empty string.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be an "out of the box solution" as much as a possible approach but yeah, your're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ path=/sdd/ee/publ/xmlfile_555.xml
$ echo ${path##*/}
xmlfile_555.xml
$ path=${path##*/}
$ echo ${path%.xml}
xmlfile_555
$ path=${path%.xml}
$ echo ${path##*_}
555
```